# Core Data Fetched Properties - Basics

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

With Core Data Fetched Properties, how do I perform this simple request:

I want the Fetched Property (`myFetchProp`) to be on store `StoreA`, and it should do:

```
[myFetchProp getMeRecordWithPredicate:@“X == 35” inEntity:@“entityH” fromStore:StoreB];
```

Forgive my wrong-syntax, but I suppose my point is easy to understand.

I can’t find any simple and clear example on the net. I presume that should not be so difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [does anyone have a working example of a fetched-property in core-data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341853/does-anyone-have-a-working-example-of-a-fetched-property-in-core-data)

Comment: Yes, I already saw this post before. That is not exactly what I call simple though. I wish there were a more basic use case.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have just read Marcus S. Zarra's [*Core Data: Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud*](https://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data) (2nd edition) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898966/prefer-property-accessor-or-kvc-style-for-accessing-core-data-properties) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906887/potential-reference-count-issues-unless-grabbing-fresh-reference-in-background-t)) let me quote it on the topic:

> In practice, I have found fetched properties to be less useful and
>   less flexible than either creating a stored fetch request or building
>   the fetch request in code. Usually when a situation calls for a
>   fetched property, it tends to be easier to subclass the entity in
>   question, perform an `NSFetchRequest` in code, and return the results.

So the assumption that fetched properties can be simple may be wrong.

Comment: This is giving me headaches. Even though I think I followed all the details I could find and I get no error or crash in my code, I always find zero items as the result of my FETCHED_PROPERTY, even when setting an empty predicate (though the entity has more than thirty items). I must be missing some obvious detail.

Comment: I finally got the thing working. In case someone else is in the same situation, this is the post that gave me the hint I needed to get out of trouble: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172495/fetched-properties-as-properties-of-an-nsmanagedobject-subclass